# Finding Model/Tool name in custom Toolbox via ArcPy/Python?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder, toolbox

We have a folder housing all custom Toolboxes/Models for our schema updates. We are attempting to automate these Toolboxes in upper environments. The initial problem is, I am unsure what Model name people are going to use.

How can I extract the Model name with Arcpy/Python then use this information with `ap.GetParameterInfo`?

The goal is to reset one required parameter in each environment.

Current failing code base:

```
import os
import arcpy as ap

_dir = r'D:\foo\bar' # folder with all the toolboxes

_lsdir = os.listdir(_dir)

for _tbx in _lsdir:
  _tb = ap.ImportToolbox("{0}\{1}".format(_dir, _tbx), "fakealias")
  print _tbx, _tb
  _p = ap.GetParameterInfo(_tb)
  for p in _p:
    print p.name, p.parameterType, p.value
```

Current Error output:

```
20190419_AddFC.tbx 'module 'fakealias' (built-in)'
AttributeError: Object: GetParameterInfo tool <module 'fakealias' (built-in)> not found.
```

I've successfully printed the `ap.GetParameterInfo` from a single Toolbox but only when hardcoding the Model name. This will not work long term.

Code formatting did not take on original publish.

---

This answered the initial question.

```py
    import os
    import arcpy as ap

    _dir = r'D:\foo\bar' # folder with all the toolboxes

    _lsdir = os.listdir(_dir)

    for _tbx in _lsdir:
      _tb = ap.ImportToolbox("{0}\{1}".format(_dir, _tbx), "fakealias")
      print _tbx
      for _t in dir(_tb):
        if "__" not in _t:
          print _t
          _p = ap.GetParameterInfo(_t)
          for p in _p:
            print p.name, p.parameterType, p.value
```

Comment: try a raw string (forward slashes are generally bad unless you want escape characters):
`ap.ImportToolbox(r"{0}\{1}".format(_dir, _tbx), "fakealias")`

Comment: I tested your suggestion and result is the same error. Even switching to '/' fails.

Comment: Use `os.path.join` to combine your paths instead of format.

Comment: I tested your suggestion, results are the same. I'm thinking there has to be a step in between the getting "_tb" and GetParameterInfo. All the ESRI documentation shows a string value in GetParameterInfo("modelname").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the ParameterInfo on the TBX, not a tool. This function works on a tool itself, not the higher level toolbox.

You can use a built in like `dir` to achieve your goal. You'll probably want to skip the dunder functions (if __ not in name):

```
for t in dir(_tb):
     if "__" not in t:
         print(t)
         _p = arcpy.GetParameterInfo(t)
         for p in _p:
            print p.name, p.parameterType, p.value
```

Comment: Actually I needed the dunder functions as there were other items under the dir(_tb) were returning other than the Model name. This worked.